# Domain of convergence and uniform convergence of $f(x) = \frac{1}{kx^2+1}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

So we started learning functional sequences and at the moment I am trying to investigate the following functional sequence:

$$f_k(x) = \frac{1}{kx^2+1}$$.

My main goal is to find the domain of convergence and decide whether or not the convergence of this sequence is uniform convergence.

Unfortunately I am stuck (just started learning and it's my first task ever regarding the topic) and do not know precisely how to write things out clearly enough so that it would be "bulletproof". If someone could help me, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Surely you mean $f_k(x) = ...$ ?

Comment: I have taken the liberty of changing $f(x)$ to $f_k(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: $f_k(x) =1$ for all $k$ if $x=0$. Otherwise $f_k(x) \to 0$. $f_k(\frac 1 {\sqrt k})=\frac 1 2$. Now apply definition of uniform convergence to show that this sequence does not converge uniformly.

However if $|x| \geq r$ for some $r>0$ then $f_k(x) |
\leq \frac 1 {kr^{2}+1} $ so the convergence is uniform on $\{x: |x| \geq r\}$.